# Most Efficient Way to Use Singleton Classes

Tags: c++, design-patterns, singleton, pass-by-reference

In C++, I use a singleton class and refer to the only instance in another class. I'm wondering what is the most efficient way to access this instance since it is a large data structure. I considered these things.

1. Getting a reference from the singleton class, other than passing the data structure by value
2. Using a global instance in my second class which uses the singleton class:

   ```
   Singleton* singleInstance;

   SingletonUser::SingletonUser ()
   {
       singleInstance = Singleton::getInstance(); //passes the single instance by   reference, then it will be used in the class wherever needed
   }
   ```
3. Doing the same thing inside a function of the second class so that I get a reference to the singleton class's instance when I want it (Need to access it several times in several functions).

I'm not sure which practice is the best one. Can someone explain, and if there is a more efficient way, explain that too?

Thanks!

Comment: If your `getInstance()` method returns a pointer as in your 2nd example, then no matter what size the object has, you're only paying for cost of invoking the `getInstance()` method and copying a pointer.  What, exactly, are you trying to optimize?

Comment: @ André Caron: The time. The Singleton class has a data structure which is pretty large. That is why I thought of passing by reference. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: @Izza: But if you're not passing it by value, then a copy is never being made (and if you were, it wouldn't be a singleton in the first place). What other way besides returning a reference did you have in mind?

Comment: 4. [Not using a singleton](http://jalf.dk/blog/2010/03/singletons-solving-problems-you-didnt-know-you-never-had-since-1995/).

Comment: @ André Caron: Yes, that is why I chose pass by reference. Other than that, the options mentioned, either keeping a global copy of accessing it from the singleton class as it is needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're passing your singleton instance by value, then it's not really a singleton, is it?

Simply return a reference (or a pointer) to the instance whenever you need to access it (#1). Caching the reference once for each client is only going to add complexity and almost certainly won't be any faster.

I'm not sure what the difference is between #1 and #3, besides added complexity. Both use a function to access the singleton instance via a reference/pointer.

Comment: I was under the impression that if you need to do it several times in the class, that it is better to cache. But I see what you mean. Since it will happen for each user, won't be much useful. thanks!

Comment: @Izza: But you'd be caching a pointer! How would it be faster to get a pointer from your instance instead of the singleton class?

Comment: yes, I get it, it is not a good way. Thanks for the expalnation.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly in C++ avoid pointers when possible, instead pass by reference:

```
Singleton& Singleton::getInstance() {
    return *singleton;
}
```

Then in the code:

```
Singleton& st = Singleton::getInstance();
st.someFunction();
```

Answer (score 1):

Your option #3 is most preferable.  Try to not cache references unnecessarily - those cached references tend to be a maintenance burden as time goes on.

And just in general, try avoid the singleton pattern.  In C++, a global function (non-member) is just as good and allows the design to evolve.

Comment: If I read #3 right, then it's caching a reference once for each client instance (whereas #1 gets the reference from the class itself).

Comment: @Cameron:  you might be right.  If so I mean #1.  In any case, needless caching == bad.

Comment: @mcmcc: I thought singletons are preferred over global functions. Why is a global function is better than Singleton?

Comment: posted why globals over singleton as a separate question.